# Click on HREF that begins with a string

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, href

I'm having problems trying to click on a href into a webpage. The href is included in "a" tag and it begins like this "http://trial.xxxyyy". How to set a string that allows me to click on a href that begins with the before mentioned string? I think queryselector is the key but i'm not familiar with it.

P.s the page is quite empty so there's not too much html.

Comment: please remember to include your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `[attribute^=value]` [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), it will selects every  element whose href attribute value begins with special value.

Sample code as below:

```
Public Sub ClickTest()

    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "<the website url>"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.Document.querySelector("a[href^='https://www.bing']").Click

    End With
End Sub
```

the website resource like this:

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/"> Google</a><br />
<a class="link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us"> Microsoft</a><br />
<a class="link" href="https://www.bing.com/"> Bing</a><br />
<a class="link" href="https://www.bing.com/search?q=vba&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=vba&sc=6-3&sk=&cvid=400A0A54265148289028B12BE5D9E3A4">Bing search</a>
```

[Note] If there have multiple elements match the filter, by using the above code, it will get the first item.